# Where is the RadialGradientBrush in WinRT XAML?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

[image]

Building XAML WinRT application & noticed the RadialGradientBrush is nowhere to be found?
Where is the RadialGradientBrush in WinRT XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, in this initial version, RadialGrandientBrush is not supported.

Comment: "initial version"... :(

Comment: Yeah, still true in Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

The radial gradient brush, which is an essential part of xaml IMHO is not supported. I'm hoping this will change. I heard Microsoft felt the brush was not very metro but it is used in huge number if otherways like logos, games etc.